How to export archive of macOS console "Hello world" application with xcodebuild?
There is newly created in Xcode-16.0 (16A242d) macOS 'Command Line Tool', a "Hello world" project.
Immediately after creation of such a project in Xcode you're able to successfully archive it from command line with the following, for example, command:
xcodebuild -scheme hw -archivePath hw archive 

But if you try to export this archive with the command
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath hw.xcarchive -exportPath . -exportOptionsPlist ./ExportOptions.plist

and the following ExportOptions.plist content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>mac-application</string>
</dict>
</plist>

, you'll get:
2024-09-19 21:11:15.093 xcodebuild[68014:8641879] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path "/var/folders/yn/fgtypmdj65l8cz2l0q18s2t40000gn/T/hw_2024-09-19_21-11-15.091.xcdistributionlogs".
2024-09-19 21:11:15.133 xcodebuild[68014:8641879] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionMethodManager orderedDistributionMethodsForTask:archive:logAspect:]: Error = Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodManagerErrorDomain Code=2 "Unknown Distribution Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Distribution Error}
2024-09-19 21:11:15.140 xcodebuild[68014:8641879] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionMethodManager orderedDistributionMethodsForTask:archive:logAspect:]: Error = Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodManagerErrorDomain Code=2 "Unknown Distribution Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Distribution Error}
2024-09-19 21:11:15.145 xcodebuild[68014:8641879] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionMethodManager orderedDistributionMethodsForTask:archive:logAspect:]: Error = Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodManagerErrorDomain Code=2 "Unknown Distribution Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Distribution Error}
error: exportArchive exportOptionsPlist error for key "method" expected one {} but found mac-application

** EXPORT FAILED **

, while archive can be successfully opened and exported with Xcode's 'Archives Organizer'
Nothing from this or this helps.
I've tried already all those listed in 'xcodebuild -help' output 'methods':
    method : String

        Describes how Xcode should export the archive. Available options: app-store-connect, release-testing, enterprise, debugging, developer-id, mac-application, and validation. The list of options varies based on the type of archive. Defaults to debugging. Additional options include app-store (deprecated: use app-store-connect), ad-hoc (deprecated: use release-testing), and development (deprecated: use debugging).

as well as different 'empty' values (i. e. <string></string>), but always get the same error.
Interesting that newly created "Hello world" SwiftUI project can be exported this way without troubles.
Just in case, I have no Apple Developer Program membership.
Any idea?
